# New errors in camera_pose_calibration

Tags: kinect, ros-hydro, github, git, camera-pose-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My old question:

http://answers.ros.org/question/115111/errors-in-camera_pose_calibration-launch-for-3-kinects/

A possible solution from an older one:

http://answers.ros.org/question/43035/errors-on-camera_pose_calibration-startup/

I cloned this repo and put in in a folder ahead of the others in my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.  The original camera_pose is there but I think it's been superceded.

https://github.com/jbohren-forks/camera_pose

Now I'm getting new errors:

```
[ERROR] [1389648551.704498369]: Failed to load nodelet [/aggregated_image_viewer] of type [image_view/image]: Unable to load plugin for transport 'raw', error string:
MultiLibraryClassLoader: Could not create object of class type image_transport::RawSubscriber as no factory exists for it. Make sure that the library exists and was explicitly loaded through MultiLibraryClassLoader::loadLibrary()

[capture_exec-19] process has died [pid 20981, exit code 1, cmd /home/robot2/Desktop/Testspace/camera_pose/camera_pose_calibration/src/camera_pose_calibration/multicam_capture_exec.py kinect_1 kinect_2 kinect_3 request_interval:=interval_filtered __name:=capture_exec __log:=/home/robot2/.ros/log/77d43c0e-7c99-11e3-9411-b8ca3a789964/capture_exec-19.log].
log file: /home/robot2/.ros/log/77d43c0e-7c99-11e3-9411-b8ca3a789964/capture_exec-19*.log

[cal_optimizer-20] process has died [pid 21005, exit code 1, cmd /home/robot2/Desktop/Testspace/camera_pose/camera_pose_calibration/src/camera_pose_calibration/run_optimization_online.py __name:=cal_optimizer __log:=/home/robot2/.ros/log/77d43c0e-7c99-11e3-9411-b8ca3a789964/cal_optimizer-20.log].
log file: /home/robot2/.ros/log/77d43c0e-7c99-11e3-9411-b8ca3a789964/cal_optimizer-20*.log

[capture_monitor-21] process has died [pid 21008, exit code 1, cmd /home/robot2/Desktop/Testspace/camera_pose/camera_pose_calibration/src/camera_pose_calibration/capture_monitor.py kinect_1 kinect_2 kinect_3 __name:=capture_monitor __log:=/home/robot2/.ros/log/77d43c0e-7c99-11e3-9411-b8ca3a789964/capture_monitor-21.log].
log file: /home/robot2/.ros/log/77d43c0e-7c99-11e3-9411-b8ca3a789964/capture_monitor-21*.log

[aggregated_image_viewer-22] process has died [pid 21034, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/image_view/image_view image:=aggregated_image __name:=aggregated_image_viewer __log:=/home/robot2/.ros/log/77d43c0e-7c99-11e3-9411-b8ca3a789964/aggregated_image_viewer-22.log].
log file: /home/robot2/.ros/log/77d43c0e-7c99-11e3-9411-b8ca3a789964/aggregated_image_viewer-22*.log
```

These are the current errors I'm getting.  If anyone has ideas, I'd love to hear them?  Or alternatives to multiple Kinect extrinsic calibration in Hydro?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/117421/new-errors-in-camera_pose_calibration/) by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 429 on 2014-01-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-01-13**:
Do you have the image transport plugins installed ("sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-image-transport-plugins")? Answer is probably yes, just want to make sure.

**Comment by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on 2014-01-13**:
Yes, I just ran it and everything was already the latest version.  If you know of any other packages for multiple Kinects, I'm very willing to try them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Funny enough, I think you actually have answered my question in another one from a year ago: http://answers.ros.org/question/50091/image-transport-issue-in-rviz-groovy-beta-1/  I'm betting it's having Fuerte on my package path. Let me know if you think this is it, although I only added share/stacks.

---

Originally posted by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) with karma: 429 on 2014-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0